# Swift 3 alternative for NSStringFromCGSize

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, nsstring

In Objective-C we have `NSStringFromCGSize` method that converts `CGSize` to `NSString`. I want to make my code as **Swifty** as possible and I don't want to use this vintage method.

```
public func NSStringFromCGSize(_ size: CGSize) -> String
```

**Is there a Swift 3 API for that?** I know I could easily code a helper function but I might be reinventing the wheel, maybe there is already something like that built in into the framework.

Please help.

Comment: NSStringFromSize is from the Foundation framework, not from Objective-C. What is the problem with using it?

Comment: @MartinR Cause syntax is not swift-3-like enough.

Comment: The syntax you show is exactly as the documentation shows, so maybe file a complaint with Apple.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in using `NSStringFromCGSize(sizeRef)` function

Comment: As I said, I'm looking for a more swift 3 like alternatives.

Comment: You could file a bug report suggesting that those functions (and their counterparts like CGSizeFromString)  are "imported as member functions" in the spirit of https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0044-import-as-member.md. I don't think there is anything better as of now.

Comment: Do you need just *some string* (in which case you could use string interpolation or the `debugDescription` method) or do you need a string in a format which can be converted back to the original CGSize?

Comment: `NSStringFromCGSize(size)` is probably good if you need to convert it back, e.g. `CGSizeFromString(string)`. Options good for debugging include `String(describing: size)`; simple string interpolation; or `size.debugDescription`. It depends upon what the intended purpose of this string is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just encase your CGSize in `\()` like

```
let string = "\(CGSize.zero)"
```

Comment: I don't know why this is down-voted. `CGSize` conforms to `CustomDebugStringConvertible`, so if for just debugging purposes, simple string interpolation is excellent approach. Now, admittedly, if OP wanted it for some other purpose (for `CGSize` to string and back), then `NSStringFromCGSize()` and `CGSizeFromString()` seem like more reliable mechanism. Regardless, I don't think this deserved a down-vote...

Answer (score 2):

In swift 4 we can use

```
let string = NSCoder.string(for: size)
```